# Parsing String in JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I need to parse a JSON Object.

JSONObject sample is:

```
{
    "ResponseAsJSON": [
        "java.util.HashMap",
        {
            "id": 4320,
            "ffoo": 1431572400,
            "foo1": "OT-RNO",
            "foo2": 1,
            "foo3": [
                "java.util.HashMap",
                {
                    "Value": 22,
                    "Unit": "pounds"
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
}
```

In this sample as we can see after `ResponseAsJSON` there is `java.util.HashMap` written which indicates that

```
{
            "id": 4320,
            "ffoo": 1431572400,
            "foo1": "OT-RNO",
            "foo2": 1,
            "foo3": [
                "java.util.HashMap",
                {
                    "Value": 22,
                    "Unit": "pounds"
                }
            ]
```

}

is of type HashMap, similarly after `foo3`

```
[
                "java.util.HashMap",
                {
                    "Value": 22,
                    "Unit": "pounds"
                }
]
```

it means inside square bracket `[ ]` value and unit is stored as `MAP`.

Basically structure is like after every attribute within square bracket first element is type followed by actual value.

I want to parse this object such that it will understand this notation.
After parsing It should look like

```
{
    "ResponseAsJSON": {
        "id": 4320,
        "ffoo": 1431572400,
        "foo1": "OT-RNO",
        "foo2": 1,
        "foo3": {
            "Value": 22,
            "Unit": "pounds"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to parse this in java ?

Comment: You can use Google's Gson library: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

Comment: You can also refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174970/converting-deeply-nested-json-to-java-object-and-vice-versa/30175534#30175534

Comment: `["java.util.HashMap",{` this is not valid json

Comment: I am not saying it is a valid one.