# convert nested realm object to json in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I have nested realm object defined in my react-native app as:

```
export const userSchema = {
  name: 'User',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'string',
    user_id: 'string',
    password: 'string',
    demographics: 'Demographics',
    notes: 'string'
  }
}

export const demographicsSchema = {
  name: 'Demographics',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    age: 'int',
    height: 'float',
    weight: 'float',
    gender: 'int',
  }
}
```

When I queried `User` from realm, I want to convert it to Json and send to backend server via http request. However, after searching for modules to convert realm object to Json, I didn't find any helpful content to do this sepecific task. If anyone knows a simple way to convert nested realm object to Json in react-native, I would be appreciated.

Comment: it a nested object , i think you should take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174970/converting-deeply-nested-json-to-java-object-and-vice-versa

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Not what I'm looking for, realmObject is different.

Comment: on what they are diffrent from a nested object ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Yes, and I'm specifically asking for serialize realmObject to Json. If you want to use `gson`, at least you have to know what the string structure looks like.

Answer (score 3):

Realm doesn't integrate this kind of function in his api at this time, but you can try something like this:

```
function realmToPlainObject(realmObj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(realmObj));
}
```

Or like that, but it will be really slow! :

```
var plainResults = Array.prototype.map.call(resultsCars, (car) => {
  var object = {};

  for (var property of YourSchema.properties) {
    object[name] = car[name];
  }

  return object;
});
```

I know that can be redundant, but a better way would be to create the json object by getting each key you want in your realmObject.

Comment: This is really uncomfortable

Comment: I know... but try the first function with `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, that should works great! :)

Comment: Eh...not really. If at least one of your field is List Type in this RealmObject, and if you have too many entries in that List Type, then this function is computationally expensive to execute. For ex, if you have a field as `car: 'Car[]'` and you have thousands of `Car`s in that list, this function could take quite a bit of time to finish.

Comment: Yes I understand if you have big nested object, that's going to by very long... But actually there is no other solution as I know from Realm and the official documentation...

Comment: Yes, which is quite sad, because to copy values in the `Proxy` object is not trivial