# How to parse symbols as JSON keys in Java with Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, symbols

I want to get some ideas to handle a JSON structure like this.
Especially for the '/' key.

```
{
    "tree":{
        "/":"1234567890"
    },
    "parents":null
}
```

I created this (works if I replace / with slash in the given JSON)

```
private class Test {
    private SubDirectory tree;
    private String parents;
}

private class SubDirectory {
    private String slash;
    // private String /; obviously not working :D
}
```

using Gson with a InputStreamReader and then:

```
Test p = gson.fromJson(reader, Test.class);
```

So my first idea is to check `reader` and replace that / to slash.
But really ?! ...

Comment: Use a `TreeMap<String, String> tree` rather than a custom object

Comment: @dpr thanks for the link, it helps to go on. I was searching but I missed that map stuff... so I came up with this symbol string to highlight the problem with a custom obj.

Comment: @dpr Can you please link it to this stack overflow url? It fits much better. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174970/converting-deeply-nested-json-to-java-object-and-vice-versa . The variable type Map<String, String> solved my problem.